# scrollbar issue after upgrade to mountain lion vs fresh install

Tags: css, macos, browser, webkit

I have banged my head in the wall for some time now. 
I have three computers with mountain lion.

I have a webpage where centered in the middle is a div with text that can scroll. 
Always looked very nice and scrollbars totally invisible.

Tried on my third newly and freshly installed mountain lion computer and the same page with the same scrollable div looks awful.

The thing is that the new fresh install provides the "correct" and expected behavior similar to other operating systems and inline with the specs for mountain lion.

the problem is that if you are on an os x version prior to mountain lion OR if you have upgraded to mountain lion from a previous version. You still have the "old" invisible scroll bars.

Setting the parent div to a slightly smaller size and making the parent divs overflow hidden solves the issue with CSS.

The question is if it is possible to get the mountain lion scrollbars after an upgrade, as I get with a fresh install.

Cheers

PS I was about to post two images but apparently that is not possible if I dont have 10 reputation? strange rule DS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the system preference? there you can select how the scrolling should behave visually like

- Automatically based on mouse or trackpad
- when scrolling
- always

The first entry should give you your desired behaviour.

-Anton